# Linq to SQL Stored Procedures with Multiple Results

Tags: c#

I have a stored procedure that selects from multiple tables

The calling method in the class the inherits from DataContext is as follows

[Function(Name = "dbo.BASE_Product_Retrieve")]

```
    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_Product))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_Product_Version))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_ItemPrice))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_VendorItem))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_ProductAttachment))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_ItemPrice_Version))]


    public IMultipleResults BASE_Product_Retrieves([Parameter(Name = "ProductId", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> productId, [Parameter(Name = "Version", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> version)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), productId, version);
        return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

when i call it from my class

var x=RetrieveProductList.GetResult < BASE_ItemPrice > ();

it gives me the following exception

The required column 'ItemPriceId' does not exist in the results.

knowing that ItemPriceId is a clumn that exists in that table!!

Answer (score 1):

How *exactly* are you using it? IIRC, you need to access the grids in the right order (it is just an `IDataReader`, ultimately).

Or to quote: "Retrieves the next result as a sequence of a specified type."

See also the note on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534218.aspx):

> You must use the GetResult(TElement)
>   pattern to obtain an enumerator of the
>   correct type, based on your knowledge
>   of the stored procedure.

So if you want the 3rd grid, I expect you need to call `GetResult` twice (with appropriate types, and discard them) before you can read the 3rd grid.

Answer (score 0):

from the form i hav RetrieveProductList of type RetrieveProductList.

i call it as follows
var x=RetrieveProductList.GetResult < BASE_ItemPrice > ();

this method is in a class that i use in my form

public IMultipleResults RetriveProducts((int ItemId, int Version)

```
    {
        return db.BASE_Product_Retrieves(ItemId, Version);
    }
```

and The calling method in the class the inherits from DataContext is as follows

[Function(Name = "dbo.BASE_Product_Retrieve")]

```
    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_Product))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_ItemPrice))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_VendorItem))]

    [ResultType(typeof(BASE_ProductAttachment))]


    public IMultipleResults BASE_Product_Retrieves([Parameter(Name = "ProductId", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> productId, [Parameter(Name = "Version", DbType = "Int")] System.Nullable<int> version)
    {
        IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())), productId, version);
        return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
    }
```

while debugging when it reaches

var x=RetrieveProductList.GetResult < BASE_ItemPrice > ();

it gives me that exception!!!

Comment: Yes, but in what order does the SP return the grids? The key word is *next* - i.e. each call to GetResult expects to parse the *next* grid with the type you specify.

Comment: the same as i defined them up there

Answer (score 0):

i applied what you told me and it somehow worked,the exception is no longer exist but the problem now is that it did not return any value,i used a data grid view an set its data source to

RetrieveProductList.GetResult < BASE_ItemPrice > ();

it returns the columns,but empty!!!!